# deleteMany in mongodb with filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, delete-method

```
Orders
id:1101, supplier:"000822",article:004970,stock:150
id:1102, supplier:"000822",article:004975,stock:100
id:1103, supplier:"000822",article:004650,stock:120
id:1104, supplier:"000822",article:004655,stock:130
id:1105, supplier:"000822",article:004975,stock:140
id:1106, supplier:"000823",article:004980,stock:150
id:1107, supplier:"000823",article:004990,stock:110
```

In the above data, I want to delete 2 records and with the filter supplier and article.

So I do:

```
const filter = "{ supplier: '000822', article: 004970}, {supplier: '000822', article: 004975}";
Orders.deleteMany(filter)
.then((result) => {
  console.log("result: " + result.deletedCount);
    ...
})
.catch(err => {
  ...
});
```

I get error: {"message":"Parameter "filter" to deleteMany() must be an object, got { supplier: '000822', article: 004970}, {supplier: '000822', article: 004975}"}

What do I wrong?

Comment: You have one document with  `supplier:"000822",article:004970` and two documents with `supplier:"000822",article:004975`.  So, you want to delete 3 documents?

Comment: You pass a string, you must pass an object as parameter.

Comment: Yes so I used: JSON.parse(filter) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the conditions in a top level `$or`, using an object instead of a string, like

```
const filter = {"$or": [
                        {supplier: '000822', article: 004970}, 
                        {supplier: '000822', article: 004975}
               ]};
```

Comment: This was the right solution. I still got the message that I needed an object so I did: JSON.parse(filter) and it worked.